# Comparing 2 different values returns true

Tags: php

I came across this while playing with php

```
$test1 = '123abc';
$test2 = 123;

var_dump($test1); echo "<br />";
var_dump($test2); echo "<br />";

$test3 = ($test1 == $test2) ? True : False;
var_dump($test3);
```

This resulted in:

```
string(6) "123abc" 
int(123) 
bool(true)
```

Could someone explain why $test3 came out true?

using "===" would make that false but that would be due to comparing string to int.

Also notice if I force *(string)$test2* it would give me the expected *false*, and forcing *(int)$test1* returns the expected *true*;

Does this mean $test3 return true because PHP automatically converted $test1 into **int** before comparison?

Comment: I wish I understood why I so often see PHP examples of `someboolean ? true : false`. If the condition expression is a boolean, the ternary adds no value.

Comment: Thanks! Never knew that, always thought you have to have the ternary

Comment: No; in fact even if the condition is not strictly a Boolean, `(bool) $condition` accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the details here](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/string-equals-zero-php-240.html):

> **a string' == 0** also evaluates to true because **any string is converted
>   into an integer when compared with an integer.** If PHP can't properly
>   convert the string then it is evaluated as 0. So 0 is equal to 0,
>   which equates as true.

Also, in [the official PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> To explicitly convert a value to integer, use either the (int) or
>   (integer) casts. **However, in most cases the cast is not needed, since
>   a value will be automatically converted if an operator, function or
>   control structure requires an integer argument.**

Comment: Thanks for the links and info!